# Gradle cannot get property ':' on a null object

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I downloaded a project for Road Detection for Android from:
https://github.com/wahibhaq/android-opencv-lanedetection

And am trying to build the project on Android Studio but the build.gradle file is giving me the following error:

```
Gradle 'android-opencv-lanedetection-master' project refresh failed
  Error: Cannot get property ':' on null object
```

I used Android Studio's option of importing a non-Android Studio project and am currently unable to build.

I have already searched for possible solutions, none of them replicate the error that I have encountered, all of the reported errors have a suffix to ':' e.g. ':username' ':lib' etc. whereas the error I encountered does not have anything of such sort nor has a similar question been asked. Although I have already tried out the solutions provided in the other similar questions which included removing all gradle-*-1.8 files and restarting Android Studio, or replacing "apply plugin: "android" with apply plugin: "android-library" and so on.

I would appreciate any help on the matter.

Comment: "replacing "apply plugin: "android" with apply plugin: "android-library"" -- those recommendations are both out of date. The proper plugins for the current version of Android Studio and Gradle for Android are `com.android.application` and `com.android.library`. Beyond that, this project seems to depend upon a non-existent module (`':OpenCV Library - 2.4.6'`).

Comment: Is there a workaround for that? I tried referencing/importing the libraries.
I also tried replicating the project as a new Android Studio project and it said that native libraries were missing. Importing those didn't work either.

Comment: "Is there a workaround for that?" -- I do not know what "that" is. You might consider filing an issue on that project's issue tracker, asking for more thorough documentation.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. by "that" I mean't maybe another OpenCV Library that could be referenced here.

Comment: Yeah, you would have to ask the project author about that. Particularly since he is pulling in some copy that is on his hard drive, and not an artifact in a repository somewhere, for all I know, his copy of the library is a modified fork off of the original OpenCV.